# Hibernate 6 Inheritance unable to identify type. I am using hibernate 6.2.7.FINAL, Worked fine with hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate-6.x

I have this base class called Animal.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMAL")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ANIMAL_TYPE")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = Giraffe.class, name = "giraffeAnimal"),
  @Type(value = Tiger.class, name = "tigerAnimal")
})
@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
public class Animal {}
```

then tiger and giraffe classes extending animal

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Tiger")
public class Tiger extends Animal {}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Giraffe")
public class Giraffe extends Animal {}
```

then in the MAIN class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN")
public class Main {

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "main")
  private Tiger tiger;

@OneToMany(
  mappedBy = "main",
  cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
  orphanRemoval = true)

private List<Giraffe> girrafes;


}
```

problem is when I persist MAIN class in the DB with 1 giraffe object and no tiger object.. I have 1 row in the Animal Table, it is persisted correctly and the ANIMAL_TYPE discriminator column is also Giraffe, but when I retreive the MAIN class object from the DB .. i  see that I have the same Giraffe object in both Tiger and Giraffe list.

the tiger object should be null

Written a simple IT test. and this is the exception below. looks like hibernate is not able to find the correct setter.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set value of type [com.example.Girraffe]: 'com.example.Main.Tiger' (setter)     at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:88)   at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.EnhancedSetterImpl.set(EnhancedSetterImpl.java:42)     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4398)  at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntityInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:851)    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntity(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:811)    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:797)  at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.initializeInstance(InitializersList.java:71)     at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:109)  at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:86)  at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:181)  at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)   at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:361)   at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)     at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)  at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)   at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:109)    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:305)  at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:246)     at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509)  at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427)     at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:559)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in our project using Hibernate 6.4.2.Final.